# How to import relative source code in cypress using typescript for an ESM project?

Tags: typescript, cypress, es6-modules

My typescript project (`"type":"module"`) is organised as follows:

```
app
  - src
    - utils
      - util.ts
    - other-code
  - cypress
    - e2e
      - spec.cy.ts
  package.json
```

I'm trying to import `util.ts` from `spec.cy.ts` using

```
import { utilA } from "../../src/utils/util.js";
```

and encounter a `Webpack compilation error: Module not found`. Note that this is **NOT** a typo but a deliberate fully qualified ESM import as is recommended by typescript. Assume that `utilA` can have recursive dependencies all using ESM-style imports. Therefore, modifying the import statement to `import { utilA } from "../../src/utils/util.ts";` or (extensionless version) `import { utilA } from "../../src/utils/util";` is not feasible.

I believe this is related to typescript compiler settings for cypress. How can I modify it? Modifying `tsconfig.json` inside the cypress folder to the following doesn't have effect.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "types": ["cypress", "node"],
      "module": "NodeNext",
      "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

I'm using typescript 5.2 and cypress 13.

EDIT 1: A sample project that reproduces the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/mukulgupta21/cypress-ts-issue). Adding a tsconfig.json under `cypress` directory doesn't seem to take into account `module` compiler options.

Comment: What happens if you write the same import in a module that is under the `src` directory?

Comment: @AluanHaddad It works as expected. I believe the webpack compilation performed by cypress is causing the problem.

Comment: Where is `"type":"module"` setting? Is it in `package.json`?

Comment: @Maddie.Squerciati Yes

Comment: If I use `"type":"module"` in `package.json` I get a different error - the default Typescript config `cypress.config.ts` shown [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Intelligent-Code-Completion) isn't compatible with `"type":"module"`, but if I switch to the Javascript version `cypress.config.js` it works ok.

Comment: If I don't use `"type":"module"` in `package.json` and Typescript config `cypress.config.ts` - then there is no error of any kind, the spec runs ok.

Comment: Can you post a Github repo?

Comment: @Maddie.Squerciati I've updated the description with a sample repository.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this was a known [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/26827) which should have been solved after cypress upgraded to webpack v5. However, as of cypress 13.6.3, it continues to be a bug.

As suggested [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/26827#issuecomment-1612039542), I used `@cypress/webpack-preprocessor` to resolve it.

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import webpackPreprocessor from "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor";
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      let options = webpackPreprocessor.defaultOptions;
      const customOptions = {
        webpackOptions: {
          resolve: {
            extensionAlias: {
              '.js': ['.ts', '.js'],
            }
          }
        }
      };
      options.webpackOptions = {
        ...options.webpackOptions,
        ...customOptions.webpackOptions,
      }
      options.webpackOptions.module?.rules?.push({
          // every time webpack sees a TS file (except for node_modules)
          // webpack will use "ts-loader" to transpile it to JavaScript
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: [/node_modules/],
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                // skip typechecking for speed
                transpileOnly: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options));
    },
  },
});
```

Note that this also required installing `webpack`, `ts-loader`, `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-env` as `devDependencies`.

Comment: This causing error ***Can't resolve './commands'*** - how to fix it?

Comment: @Vagdevi You're right. You will have to modify the import in e2e.ts to use ESM imports as well. `import "./commands.js"`